# Android launching new Activity with Intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

I'm trying to figure out a way to bring an existing activity to the front and clear all other activities. I think I can do this with Intent.setFlags(int flags) but I'm not certain which flags to use.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I would think this would work, but it doesn't. It clears all activities including the one I'm trying to bring to the front. Is there a way to do this without clearing the activity I'm trying to bring to the front?

Answer (score 0):

You should use these flags

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

It will clear the activity hierarchy and then create your new one.